# git rm --cached is removing files from file system

Tags: git

I've started working on a project and I've added `.idea/*` to the *.gitignore* file, but it still show's up.

So I thought the file must be in the git cache so I ran `git rm --cached filename`, although it does not seems to work as it actually removes the file when I merge the branch, you can see my git commands below.

I recently started developing on a macbook pro, before I was working on ubuntu and I never had this issue.  Perhaps it has something to do with my `git` setup.

This has happened before on another project, that time when I ran `git rm --cached .` it actually removed most of the project files from the file system.

```
$ (786-rwd) git status
On branch 786-rwd
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/786-rwd'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .idea/misc.xml

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   .idea/modules.xml
    modified:   .idea/www.project.dev.iml
    modified:   app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/rwd/template/prog/bund.phtml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    skin/frontend/bootstrapped/rwd/sass/_cms-pages.scss

holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/porject
$ (786-rwd) git rm --cached .idea/modules.xml
rm '.idea/modules.xml'
holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/porject
$ (786-rwd) git rm --cached .idea/www.project.dev.iml
rm '.idea/www.project.dev.iml'

$ (786-rwd) git status
On branch 786-rwd
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/786-rwd'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .idea/misc.xml
    deleted:    .idea/modules.xml
    deleted:    .idea/www.project.dev.iml

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/rwd/template/prog/bund.phtml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    skin/frontend/bootstrapped/rwd/sass/_cms-pages.scss

holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/porject
$ (786-rwd) ls .idea/
./                       .name                    deployment.xml           encodings.xml            scopes/                  workspace.xml
../                      copyright/               dictionaries/            modules.xml              vcs.xml                  www.project.dev.iml

$ (786-rwd) git add .
holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project
$ (786-rwd) git commit -m 'theming & cleaned up git'
[786-rwd 8aa5ba8] theming & cleaned up git
 5 files changed, 24 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 .idea/misc.xml
 delete mode 100644 .idea/modules.xml
 delete mode 100644 .idea/www.project.dev.iml
 create mode 100644 skin/frontend/bootstrapped/rwd/sass/_cms-pages.scss
holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project
$ (786-rwd) git status
On branch 786-rwd
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/786-rwd' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project
$ (786-rwd) git checkout -b test-branch origin/prod
Branch test-branch set up to track remote branch prod from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'test-branch'
holy in ~/ubuntu_1404/httpdocs/project
$ (test-branch) git merge --no-ff 786-rwd 
Auto-merging app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/mobile/template/program/results.phtml
Auto-merging app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
Removing .idea/www.project.dev.iml
Removing .idea/modules.xml
Removing .idea/misc.xml
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .gitignore                                                                         |    6 +-
 .idea/misc.xml                                                                     |    5 -
 .idea/modules.xml                                                                  |    9 -
 .idea/www.project.dev.iml                                                      |    9 -
 app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/default/layout/local.xml                          |   66 ++++


$ (test-branch) ls .idea/
./              ../             .name           copyright/      deployment.xml  dictionaries/   encodings.xml   scopes/         vcs.xml         workspace.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm --cached` will mark a file as deleted in the staging area. Next time you commit, the delete will be recorded in the repository's history.
If you then merge this commit to another branch, the file is removed from disk (because Git merges your branches and then checks out the resulting tree).

Comment: how can I get git to just ignore the file? I've added it to gitignore already

Comment: Once the delete is recorded in all branches, it should be ignored in future operations. Unfortunately this is expected behavior.

Comment: so if you want the file to be ignored by git but remain on each environments file system you need to run `rm --cached` and then replace the file on the file system after it has been removed by a `git merge`?

Comment: That happened to me before with a Magento configuration file, `Netaccess_Turpentine.xml`, I removed it with `git rm --cache` and had to replace it on each environment when I merged the branches

Comment: Yes, you have to add it manually after running merge. Best to remove it before creating branches :)

Comment: cheers. Not a problem now that I know that is how it's meant to work, just didn't seem right to me. Not much of an issue with *.idea* files anyway :)  Thanks

Comment: "you have to add it manually after running merge"? @knittl does gits workflow for simply untracking a file really involve manually copy/pasting in the file system? That seems very counter to the whole philosophy of git.

Comment: @jmdeamer it's been a while since I wrote that comment and TBH I don't remember exactly what I meant back then :) For simply untracking a file, you remove it (`git rm` to untrack AND delete from the filesystem; or `git rm --cached` to untrack only but leave it on the file system). But when merging a branch on which a file was untracked can result in "surprising" results. The OP question was exactly about this (= I removed a file on branch and it's getting removed from the filesystem when merging this branch).